# Binding Url to Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, odbc

I want to bind the `url` to `GridView` but I don't know how.

For example when I type the `http://localhost:12345/example.aspx?FirstName=John` in the `url` it will give me the result in `GridView` that shows only with the FirstName "John".

Here's my curent code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ' Stablish ODBC Connection
    Dim con As New OdbcConnection("DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=WJNJPHR8TCX8P\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Fabrics;Integrated Security=True;")
    ' Query Command
    Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM [Client] WHERE [FirstName] = ?", con)
    con.Open()

    ' Gets the path (Example.aspx)
    Dim path As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
    ' Gets the host (localhost)
    Dim host As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
    ' Gets the whole url (localhost:24124/Example.aspx)
    Dim url As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
    ' Parse the query string variables into a NameValueCollection
    Dim qscoll As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url)

    ' Iterate through the collection and shows the result in MsgBox
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    For Each s As String In qscoll.AllKeys
        sb.Append(s & " = " & qscoll(s) & vbCrLf)
    Next s
    MsgBox(sb.ToString)

    ' Gets all keys and values in query string and shows it on MsgBox
    For Each key As String In HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.AllKeys
        MsgBox("Key: " + key + "  Value: " + Request.QueryString(key))
    Next key

    Dim FName As String = Request.QueryString("FirstName")
    Dim par1 As New OdbcParameter
    par1.OdbcType = OdbcType.NVarChar
    par1.Value = FName
    par1.ParameterName = "@FirtName"
    cmd.Parameters.Add(par1)


    'Shows the result in Data Grid
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader()) '==> Error: Invalid use of default parameter
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Any help will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your query string directly with

```
Dim firstName as string = Request.QueryString("firstName")
```

Then you must pass it as a parameter of the query before executing it

```
Dim par1 As New OdbcParameter
par1.DbType = DbType.String
par1.Value = firstName
par1.ParameterName = "@FirstName"
cmd.Parameters(1) = par1
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! @isol I'll try it :)

Comment: I tried your code and it gives me an error says **"** Invalid index 1 for this OdbcParameterCollection with Count=0 **"**. I tried to editing your code but it gives me the same error.

Comment: I tried to edit the `par1.DbType = DbType.String` to `par1.OdbcType = OdbcType.NVarChar`

Comment: Sorry, try  `cmd.Parameters.Add(par1)`

Comment: I tried it also and gives me an error says **"** Invalid Use of Parameters **"** Thanks for your help maybe I'll debug it on myself :) @isol

Comment: Remove the OR from the query `SELECT * FROM [Client] WHERE [FirstName] = ?`

Comment: Sorry, I already remove it on my syntax and it gives me the error says **"** Invalid Use of Parameter **"** .

Comment: Can you post your current code @SagaraAlmira, so I can have a check on it

Answer (score 0):

Answered my question!

Here's my code:

```
    For Each key As String In HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.AllKeys
        Dim FName As String = Request.QueryString("FirstName")
        Dim par1 As New OdbcParameter With {
            .OdbcType = OdbcType.NVarChar,
            .Value = FName,
            .ParameterName = "@FirstName"
        }
        cmd.Parameters.Add(par1)

        MsgBox("Key: " + key + "  Value: " + Request.QueryString(key))
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Next key
```

@isol Thanks for your help! :)